# Compare 2 dates in format DD/MM/YYYY with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, date

Suppose I receive two dates from the datepicker plugin in format `DD/MM/YYYY`

```
var date1 = '25/02/1985';  /*february 25th*/
var date2 = '26/02/1985';  /*february 26th*/
/*this dates are results form datepicker*/

if(process(date2) > process(date1)){
   alert(date2 + 'is later than ' + date1);
}
```

What should this function look like?

```
function process(date){
   var date;
   // Do something
   return date;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your date picker is not returning actual javascript `Date` objects? If it is then you can just compare them.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Split on the "/" and use the [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```
function process(date){
   var parts = date.split("/");
   return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
}
```

Comment: This approach would work better than the one I posted because I suspect some dates like 1/1/2000 would default to the mm/dd/yyyy format when converted to a date object. +1 for you, sir.

Comment: it should be return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] +1, parts[0]);

Comment: No, the month component of the javascript date is zero-based. Besides parts[1] + 1 would cast 1 as a string and append it to the end of the parts[1] string..

Comment: @InvisibleBacon thanks for your answer and +1. Can u plz tell me if it is  '25/02/1985' and '4/12/2015 12:00:00 AM ' . Thanks

Answer (score 13):

It could be more easier:

```
var date1 = '25/02/1985';  /*february 25th*/
var date2 = '26/02/1985';  /*february 26th*/

if ($.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', date2) > $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', date1)) {

       alert(date2 + 'is later than ' + date1);

}
```

For more details [check this](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate) out. Thanks.

Comment: Much better solution than the one accepted as answer

Answer (score 8):

```
function process(date){
   var parts = date.split("/");
   var date = new Date(parts[1] + "/" + parts[0] + "/" + parts[2]);
   return date.getTime();
}
```